# How to Convert String Array to NSData, NSData to String Array?

Tags: swift

I want to convert [String] to NSData for BLE Connection.

I know how to convert String to NSData / NSData to String.

```
// String -> NSData
var str: String = "Apple";
let data: NSData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

// NSData -> String
var outStr: String = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
```

However, how can I convert,,

```
// [String] -> NSData ???
let strs: [String] = ["Apple", "Orange"]
```

This is a sample of converting [UInt8] <--> NSData
https://gist.github.com/nolili/2bf1a701df1015ed6488

I want to convert [String] <--> NSData

```
// [String] -> NSData ??? Is it correct???
var strs: [String] = ["Apple", "Orange"]
let data2 = NSData(bytes: &strs, length: strs.count)

// NSData -> [String] ... please teach me..
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a direct answer to your question, you could ask each string in your array for its `thisString.dataUsingEncoding(_:)` and append the result to an `NSMutableData` instance until you're all done.

```
let stringsData = NSMutableData()
for string in strings {

    if let stringData = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding) {

        stringsData.appendData(stringData)

    } else {

        NSLog("Uh oh, trouble!")

    }

}
```

Of course this doesn't help you if you want to separate the strings later, so what we really need to know is how / in what environment do you intend to consume this data on the other end of your connection? If the other end uses Cocoa as well, consider just packaging it as a PLIST. Since `NSString`, `NSArray`, and `NSData` are all property list types, you can just archive your `NSArray` of `NSString` instances directly:

```
let arrayAsPLISTData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(strings)
```

...then transfer the resulting `NSData` instance to the Cocoa-aware destination and then:

```
if let newStrings: [String] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(arrayAsPLISTData) as? [String] {

    // ... do something

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry my late reply...  I want to sent the [String] to other device via BLE connection. When we sent something via BLE, We use "writeValue" method. peripherl.writeValue(data: NSData, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: *responce type*).

Comment: I used NSKeyedUnarchiver, it works!! Thank you very much. however, I dont know it's best way to convert NSData when sending msg via BLE Connection.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. What *exactly* is the BLE device doing with this data? What programming environment / language / device are you using these strings-as-data with? This is vitalninformation we need to know to even determine how to answer your question in a way you can use.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. programming environment is XCode 7.0, language is swift 2.0. I want to send a messages from iPhone A to iPhone B. iPhone A sends messages: [Stirng] after converting NSData with the function writeValue(data: NSData, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: response type) . Then, iPhone B receives NSData from the func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWriteRequests requests: [CBATTRequest]) , convert requests[n] from NSData to [String] and updates message aria.

Answer (score 24):

**Swift 4.2**

`[String]` -> `JSON` -> `Data`

```
func stringArrayToData(stringArray: [String]) -> Data? {
  return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: stringArray, options: [])
}
```

`Data` -> `JSON` -> `[String]`

```
func dataToStringArray(data: Data) -> [String]? {
  return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String]
}
```

Comment: This is perfect answer!

Answer (score 5):

I tested this in iOS 9

```
func test() {
    let originalStrings = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"]
    NSLog("Original Strings: \(originalStrings)")

    let encodedStrings = stringArrayToNSData(originalStrings)
    let decodedStrings = nsDataToStringArray(encodedStrings)
    NSLog("Decoded Strings: \(decodedStrings)")
}

func stringArrayToNSData(array: [String]) -> NSData {
    let data = NSMutableData()
    let terminator = [0]
    for string in array {
        if let encodedString = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            data.appendData(encodedString)
            data.appendBytes(terminator, length: 1)
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Cannot encode string \"\(string)\"")
        }
    }
    return data
}

func nsDataToStringArray(data: NSData) -> [String] {
    var decodedStrings = [String]()

    var stringTerminatorPositions = [Int]()

    var currentPosition = 0
    data.enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock() {
        buffer, range, stop in

        let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer)
        for var i = 0; i < range.length; ++i {
            if bytes[i] == 0 {
                stringTerminatorPositions.append(currentPosition)
            }
            ++currentPosition
        }
    }

    var stringStartPosition = 0
    for stringTerminatorPosition in stringTerminatorPositions {
        let encodedString = data.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(stringStartPosition, stringTerminatorPosition - stringStartPosition))
        let decodedString =  NSString(data: encodedString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        decodedStrings.append(decodedString)
        stringStartPosition = stringTerminatorPosition + 1
    }

    return decodedStrings
}
```

Comment: thank you Robert and sorry my late reply. your code also worked at my env. thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, @ketancho, Good enough to mark it as the answer? (It would be my first :-))